# How to change node icon in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

i am trying to simulate some of congestion avoidance techniques in omnet++, one of those techniques are basing on special vehicles called *super vehicles*, so i have to make those nodes (vehicles) during simulation with a different icons , the default in veins are car icon, i search a lot on which class that could has this options , but i could only find some parameters in `BaseMobility.cc`, so my question is how to change the nodes icons in veins ? , and if is it possible to change the icon of only specific nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMNeT++ stores this in a module's DisplayString property (the i tag, to be precise). The OMNeT++ manual and TicToc tutorial give a nice introduction on how to change DisplayString tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you understood it this question belongs one year ago.
first of all open omnet++ folder and find image folder you can see all of omnet++ icon in block folder.
C:\Users\user\src\omnetpp-4.6\images\block